# How to set lock wait timeout in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, locking

how do i set a lock wait timeout in sql server?

Is there anyway that I can specify maybe through JDBC

or a configuration script that I can use?

I want to make sure that my statements will only wait specific time on accessing a row with a lock

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can either issue a TSQL `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT nnnn` statement or set it in the connection string using the [`lockTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx) property.